# File.renameTo() returning false after iText upgrade

Tags: java, file, itext

We have upgraded iText version from 5.0 to 5.5.9 in few of our applications. After that we are facing issues in File.renameTo calls. Its returning false.

If we replace back the previous version of iText, it is working fine.

Once iText merges the pdf's, those pdf's are not getting moved to different folder.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can not add the snippet here. It is a normal File.renameTo(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath) call which is returning false. I feel that iText is keeping the file lock open or something like that.

Comment: Please, write a [mcve] to show the problem. _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_

Comment: This is the snippet which is returning false - File.renameTo(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath)

Comment: That is not a Snippet, more like a method declaration, this is not reproductible... what is doing Itext during this call ? Without a MCVE, there is no change we can tell you what could block from iText, unless someone had the exact situation but this is unlikely.

Comment: general rule: no code, no answers

Comment: *"upgraded iText version from 5.0 to 5.5.9"* - up to the 5.3.x versions `PdfCopy.getImportedPageImpl` closed the `PdfReader` instance from which previous pages had been imported if the current call imported from a different instance. This was explicitly changed as it interfered with multiple use cases. This change or a similar one might cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code on Windows, the file may not have been closed properly, and you rely on the garbage collector to do it.
So you may try to run the same program on Linux to check this hypothesis.

This can be a regression in iText or your code was broken even with the previous version of iText, but with the difference of implementation, the garbage collector did its job before you called `File.renameTo`.

As told on the comments of your post, the single line `File.renameTo(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath)` is not enough to understand your issue. We need the context to understand the problem.

As a reminder the Java doc says :

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a file in a platform independent manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I am running the code in windows. How can we make sure that File is closed properly ? I tried to put that file in FIS and closed the stream. Still faced the same issue. Shall we try to manually call garbage collector here ?
I tried Files.move but it was giving class def not found errors even after including the jars.
By the way, I am just moving from One folder to another folder in the same drive in windows. It would obviously be platform independent.

Comment: We can make sure that your file is closed or not if you post the relevant part of your code, as requested by myself and AxelH.

Comment: I would not put the fault too quickly on the OS since this happened from the iText 5.5.9, the OS didn't changed I suppose with the version ;) .  Yes, the `renameTo` could be buggy but this is easy to check on the specific OS.

Comment: @AxelH I agree, but I have often seen the inverse behaviour : the program runs smoothly on Linux and fails on Windows because of the file locking. So when I encounter such problem I test on different OS to confirm.