# renameTo() method not works some times

Tags: java

There is a seibel application where we are using java code for importing csv files in it.This application is hosted in 2 different web server 260 and 272.

On the both servers there we have created shared folders name as : **uploaded** and **scanned**

1. Uploading csv file , it uploaded in **uploaded folder**
2. Scanning the file through Macfee sever ,file move to scanned folder

There is renameTo() for moving file from uploaded to scanned folder

```
if(uploadedFile.**renameTo**(scannedFile)){

            logger.info("File "+uploadedName+" moved to scanned files folder");

                }
                else
{

    logger.error("Failed to move file "+uploadedName+" to scanned files folder");

    }
```

**Note:**: when our request goes to 260 sever scanning always success  and file move to scanned folder
 But when our request goes to 272 it failed to move file in **scanned** folder.

If we importing 10 files 7 success but 3 failed to moved in scanned folder.
Failed comes only 272 web server.

Here we using java 1.6 , so there is no moveTo()method for moving file.

Please suggest me why is failing in 272 web server.Same code is deployed on both server.

Is it java code issue or server issue?

Comment: I have read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41587603/4391450) lately and found it interesting about this method. What is the difference between those server ? The OS, 272 is on Windows I guess ?

Comment: If it's a Windows server. Maybe the file is locked by another process that time.

Answer (score 0):

For above issue we have used **FileUtils** from io package of File class
**FileUtils.moveFile(uploaded ,scanned);**

Using this csv file is moving from uploaded to scanned folder in both web server.